# Total Score ranking algorithm

Tags: algorithm, ranking, rating, reddit, scoring

Background;

I am looking for a way to calculate the score of a piece of audio based on listeners feedback.  Each time a user listens to the track, they must vote if they like it, a simple yes or no.  Then each track has a score, based on the number of yes and no votes.

Additionally I would like to decay the value of each vote uniformly over the course of 31 days, so after this amount of time, its value is 0 and doesn't contribute to the overall total score.

I have found a lot of discussions based on reddit and hacker news ranking algorithms, but these seem to decay the total score, and not individual votes themselves.  Each vote will have a different amount of decay, based on when the vote was originally cast.

Can anyone help or recommend some material to look at?

Thanks

Comment: You will find this helpful over at cross-validated : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2563/what-are-some-of-the-best-ranking-algorithms-with-inputs-as-up-and-down-votes

Comment: Day 0, how much is a yes and no vote worth? Meaning: If the current score is X, and I vote yes/no, what will the score be now? (immediately after I vote, assuming X has not decayed in any way/sense in the mean time).

Answer (score 1):

You could model it as "yes" = 1.0 and "no" = 0.0.
Then, the value of a vote on the nth day after it was cast = (31-n)/31. Further condition this if n > 31, then set it to 0. 
Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

What acceleration do you want on the degradation. A common one is logarithmic because it is easy to implement. Score a 1 for like and a -1 for dislike. Then, when adding up the likes/disliked, divide by the number of days since the vote. On day 1, the vote will have an absolute value of 1. On day 2, it will be 1/2. On day 3, it will be worth 1/3, etc... On day 31, it will be worth 1/31 (0.03).

The problem with logarithmic degradation is that it drops very quickly. You can use many other methods, such as multiplying by log(11-d) where d=1 on the first day, 2 on the second day, and so on. It only allows 11 days of degradation. log(31-d) would allow 31 days. You need to ensure you don't try to do log(0) or log(-x).

Another problem with this entire model is how to handle things that only have old votes. What if something has nothing but likes, but all the likes are old? It will register as not liked much because all the likes have degraded.